# speed variation in BGE

Tags: game-engine

I'm making a project in BGE where I need to implement speed variations in an object with single press and long press of a key? (speed increase with long press)
please help its urgent

Comment: Typically a force would do exactly that. As longer you apply the force as bigger the velocity. But I do not know if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

add a keyboard sensor and connect it to a python controller

```
    own = cont.owner
    key_w = own.sensors['w']# can assign any key make sure the sensor is the same

        max_speed = 2
        if key_w.positive:
            if speed_var < max_speed:
              speed_var += 0.25#how quickly to accelerate  
        else:
        speed_var = 0#you can also do the same here by subtracting 0.25
# until 0 is reached...make sure you do a check that it stays above 0
```